# Website deployment from SVN

Tags: deployment, svn, hosted-svn

Does anyone use SVN to deploy their websites? If you do, could you explain your setup process and workflow or provide a link to more information? Ideally, I'd like to be able to commit to SVN and then have it also update my website. I'm currently using [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com) as a hosted SVN repository, so any answers that take that into account would be doubly appreciated.

Comment: I was considering to start using SVN for websites too. But for now I'm still using it only for JS/PHP code used by my websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used SVN in the past, then I switched to [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

I strongly encourage you to read the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). It contains lot of useful information and suggestions to use SVN in the right way.

You can start by using the `trunk` tree to store your main project development line. Each developer will work on its working copy, and execute one commit for every completed feature, fixed bug or change.

The configuration on your production server depends on the complexity of the project. If the project is simple, you can checkout a working copy and point the server to the working copy. Make sure to block the access to the `.svn` folders.

An other alternative, is to execute an export, instead of a checkout.

Comment: +1 - I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thanks for the helpful link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some providers offer the option to automatically push live the latest commits. I know [Beanstalk offers this](http://beanstalkapp.com/), have been meaning to try it. It seems that Assembla offers it as well, though it's on a paid plan.